# Pine Script, series[0] type is not integer?

Tags: pine-script

What is the cause of the error message:

```
//@version=4
study("sample")
int dep=0

if close>open
        dep:=dep+1

cma=sma(close,dep[0])

plot(cma)
```

---

error code:

```
line 11: Cannot call 'sma' with arguments (series[float], series[integer]); available overloads: sma(series[float], integer) => series[float];
```

Comment: Might I ask you why do have `dep[0]` instead of just `dep`? I often see the people use that contruction, but I can't undestand why.

Comment: Get the same result.

Comment: Yes, I know that the result is the same. I'm just curious why use `[0]`. It's 100% correct, but a bit unusual and I just interested to know the way the people come up to this format.

Comment: Use dep error reporting, try another way.

Comment: Based on other languages, a [] subscript gives you the value in the array. It sounds normal to expect that dep[0] will return an integer from the dep array(or series). Sadly this isn't the way types work in Pine script

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: you are trying to pass a `series integer` to the `sma` function, whereas the `sma` function takes only `integer`
You are making the `dep` series when trying to set it to another value. So the `dep` variable has different value on every bar, which makes it series.
You might use a pine-version of `sma` to fix the script:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_sma

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But My problem is still unresolved.Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("sample")
int dep=1

if close>open
    dep:=dep+1

//cma=sma(close,dep[0])                     //wrong

pine_sma(x, y) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1
        sum := sum + x[i] / y
    sum

//plot(pine_sma(close, 15))                 //correct

plot(dep)

plot(pine_sma(close, dep))                  //When dep type is int, its value is always 2.
                                            //Set dep type is var,Code run time error.
```

---

My problem is still unresolved.
My understanding was series[integer] should get int.Isn't it?

Comment: `series[integer] should get int.Isn't it` No. It returns `series integer`.

Comment: So, how can I get the result I want?

Comment: Couple of things:
1) in the above code, you should also give an instruction of what dep should be in the case close is not higher than open:
`if close>open
    dep:=dep+1
else
    dep:=dep`

for instance.

2) in the for loop, you should divide only at the very end, so:
`sum := sum + x[i]`

and after the for has executed:
`sum := sum/(y-1)`

Comment: Thanks for you following,This is just an example,dep is a counter,I can't get the value of dep to calculate the sam value.Others are not important.

Comment: I'm not quite understand why it's important for you to use build-in `sma` instead of `pine_sma`, which solves your problem, but I expect in nearest time (assume, next week) sma to work with `series integer`

Comment: Pine_sam also can't use series integers. Just look at the code above to understand. If the new version can solve this problem, that's great, I hope to come soon. Are you a developer of pine script?@Michel_T.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("sample", max_bars_back = 100)
var dep=1

if close>open
    dep:=dep+1

dep := min(dep, 100) // we needs some limit or must be some condition when dep := 0

pine_sma(x, y) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1
        sum := sum + x[i]
    sum / y

plot(dep)
plot(pine_sma(close, dep))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want.

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array{dot}get](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dget)

```
array.get(dep, 0)
```